# c# - GetForegroundWindow some computer Get the code is wrong?

Tags: c#

I came across a very strange problem in some computers

When I want to grab "In action ie Browser", bug some use GetForegroundWindow () the generated code is wrong.

[image]

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
private void btnAi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process p in processes)
    {
       if (!p.ProcessName.Equals("Idle"))
       {
          if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
          {
              listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName + "-" + p.MainWindowHandle);
          }
        }
     }
}


MWH = GetForegroundWindow();  // IE 11 --> 67118
```

`GetForegroundWindow()` get number is 67118, but Processes list IE 11 handler number is 67212 ???

Some computers can catch the correct number, some computers can't catch the correct number

I have confirmed the windows version.（Win 7 32bit）

IE version (IE 11.0.75)

Are consistent
SO I don't know where the problem is.

bug Some Computer is accurately

[image]

Comment: Does this behavior depend on opened IE tabs (one or more)?

Comment: Because I want to do a function, when I press the F9 button in any window, I will grab the currently active window which is the program.

But I found that on some computers, the code that was crawled did not appear in the work administrator list, and I couldn’t catch the "ie".

Comment: You are surely confusing Process.MainWindowHandle with Process.Id.  Task Manager's Processes tab does not say anything about window handles, it only shows the PID.  The MainWindowHandle is in general not very reliable, the OS does not have a way to say "this is my main window".  it assume that the first window it encounters is the main one.  IE is furthermore special because it is a single-instance app.  Starting it when it is already running gives you the wrong Process instance.